# In Orchard how do I render the editor for a ContentType on a cshtml page inside my module

Tags: handler, orchardcms, content-type

I have a contentType defined, along with a driver + handler, it works fine inside of the admin page but I want to render the editor for a contentType on a cshtml page inside my module. How do I do this and can I still get the benefit of the parts being persisted etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IContentManager.BuildEditor(...)` to produce the editor shape for a content item, and render it in your view using `@Display(Model.Whatever)`.

To deal with updates, you can also use `IContentManager.UpdateEditor(...)`, passing in an implementor of `IUpdateModel`.

`IUpdateModel` is just an Orchardy way of abstracting calls to `TryUpdateModel` and `AddModelError` that you find in regular ASP MVC controllers, so if you are rendering your editor from a custom controller you can implement it easily like this:

```
bool IUpdateModel.TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties) {
    return TryUpdateModel(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties);
}

void IUpdateModel.AddModelError(string key, LocalizedString errorMessage) {
    ModelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage.ToString());
}
```

You can find a nice succinct example in `Orchard.Blogs.Controllers.BlogAdminController`.

As an aside, you might recognise `IUpdateModel` and `prefix` from developing your content part driver - this abstraction is extremely versatile as it allows you to deal with multiple editors being updated at the same time (this is how stuff like content parts, fields etc have been implemented). It allows you to do some cool stuff like edit multiple content items on the same page.  We use this at my work to implement a custom forms editor which has some nice features like drag and drop design etc.

Comment: You're amazing thanks a bunch !

This has exposed another issue though. I have a contentPickerField on this object and it's not working when rendered this way (example : http://i.imgur.com/uJNjXMK.png ) any thoughts?

Edit : By not working I mean functionally, it doesn't pop up the window to select delegates. I can fix it visually

Comment: Hhmm, not sure - have you tried checking your browser's javascript console for errors? Also, have you checked out Orchard Custom Forms? You might find it is simpler if you are just collecting data from front end users, and you can extend it easily with workflows without having to write a great deal of code (my bad, I should have qualified your question with a "what are you trying to achieve?")

Comment: Thanks again, we're using custom forms with workflows on simpler parts of the site, but with this bit we need to create several different contentTypes on save and assign them to the correct ContentTypePickers so they're related. No javascript errors on the page :( Perhaps the scripts are rendered on the admin page?

Comment: Try wrapping your `@Display(...)` in a `@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) { ... }`, since the content picker appears to expect to be inside a form tag (in fact the whole editor will need to be if you are posting back information). I think you will run into issues using the content picker for non-admin users since it will open up a window to a page that requires access to the Dashboard, however using the existing module as a base you could probably roll your own pretty quickly.

Comment: The content item picker, like the media library picker, is not designed to be used on the front-end.